# Наведение курсора мыши на кнопку в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, button

В моей программе при некоторых условиях создаются кнопки, и мне надо отследить событие наведение курсора мыши на саму кнопку. Видел множество примеров реализации сего в xaml, но мне нужно на C#
Кто-нибудь знает как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать событие [MouseEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx). В пару к нему идет событие [MouseLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave.aspx).

Comment: Можно пример? А то я совсем уже разобраться не могу

Comment: Спасибо, уже не надо